# Eclipse (Kepler) Ignoring Context Root

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-kepler

We have a multi-module maven project.  The context root for our JAX-RS is specified in the POM and an application.xml gets generated when we do a maven build on the project.

Inside eclipse when we clean/build the project and deploy to Glassfish this context-root gets ignored and the context-root ends up being the name of the WAR file.

Is there some way to override this?    This didn't seem to be an issue in the older version of eclipse we had been using.

Comment: BTW tried changing the context on the one Dynamic Web Application module and it ignores both the original value (name of the module) and the context root I changed it to.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running your server from inside Eclipse, try right-clicking the project and going to Properties > Web Project Settings. Change the context root to what you want it to be and click Apply. Then in the servers tab, turn off Glassfish if it's running, then right click your Glassfish server and choose to clean it. Then try running your project.